# Play framework: how to pass parameters to include

Tags: include, playframework

I want to include an html file in a view and pass parameters to that include.

Can i pass parameters when using: (?)

```
#{include 'page.html' /}
```

Something along the lines of a jsp:include where you can specify which parameters you want to pass.

example: In the same page do something like

```
<jsp:include page="page.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="a" value="aValue"/>
    <jsp:param name="b" value="bValue"/>
    <jsp:param name="c" value="cVlaue"/>
</jsp:include>

<jsp:include page="page.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="a" value="aOtherValue"/>
    <jsp:param name="b" value="bOtherValue"/>
</jsp:include>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters, then you are better off making a groovy tag, rather than creating an include.

More information can be found on the Play documentation - http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates#tags

Basically, though, you would do the following

```
#{mytag param:'data', param2:'data2' /}
```

Then, in the following file `app/views/tags/mytag.html`, you would add the following (note the underscores)

```
Some html, which can access the parameters as ${_param} and ${_param2}
```